# Unable to get IOS headings

Tags: nativescript

I am not able to get megnetic heading making a compass want to get exact angle.I have tried several code , but i not getting it ,I really want to know how to get this working

```
locationmanager = CLLocationManager.alloc().init();    console.log("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@1",locationmanager.stopUpdatingHeading(),CLLocationManager.headingAvailable()
 );

console.log("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@2    ",locationmanager.heading);    locationmanager.startUpdatingHeading();    
locationmanager.didUpdateHeading = function(b,a){
console.log("########################",a.magneticHeading );
};
```

Comment: You have to implement [CLLocationManagerDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanagerdelegate?language=objc) and assign it to the delegate property of CLLocationManager (locationmanager). Then in the `locationManagerDidUpdateHeading` callback you should receive the updates. [Here](https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/ios-runtime/how-to/ObjC-Subclassing#typescript-delegate-example) is how you generally implement delegates in {N}.

Comment: @Manoj can you please make me a demo for above code so that i can picturize view for first time

Answer (score 0):

@manoj thanks for the help it really worked for me without which i think i wouldn't be able to figure out things.For all people i am sending github code to view my link how i achived it.

https://github.com/lettertoamit/activityCode-Nativescript/blob/master/kibladirection.ios.js